# ScrollView control don't display more rows by scrolling

Tags: android

The tvReceiveNumber and tvOnlyOrExceptNumber controls have many rows, so I add a ScrollView control in my UI.
I think I can display more rows using ScrollView, but I failed, the ScrollView control don't scroll to diplay more rows.
How can I do? Thanks!

BTW, if you have better way to display many rows by scrolling screen and keep the toolbar buttons such as btnEdit, btnDeleet and btnClose always display on the bottom of screen, wolud you please tell me?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/border_ui" >

    <com.google.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="a15284e3e927f18"
        ads:loadAdOnCreate="false" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/adView"  
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRuleNameTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Rule Name" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvRuleName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Rule Name" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutChecked"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutName"  
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvEnabledRule"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enabled Rule" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/chEnabledRule"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <ScrollView
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutChecked" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutOption"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvReceiveTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Receiver"
                 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvReceiveNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOptionTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Forward Option" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOnlyOrExceptNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10"  />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="#DCDCDC"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:checked="true"
            android:text="Edit" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Delete" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnClose"
            style="@style/myTextAppearance"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Close" />
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

The following code is not good too. The toolbar buttons such as btnEdit, btnDeleet and btnClose can't always display on the bottom of screen, I need to scroll UI to display toolbar, and more some rows of the tvOnlyOrExceptNumber control disappear, I don't know why?

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a15284e3e927f18"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="false" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutName"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/adView"  
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRuleNameTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Rule Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRuleName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Rule Name" />

</LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutChecked"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutName"  
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvEnabledRule"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enabled Rule" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/chEnabledRule"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>



    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutOption"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutChecked"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReceiveTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Receiver"
             />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvReceiveNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOptionTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Forward Option" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvOnlyOrExceptNumber"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10"  />
    </LinearLayout>


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#DCDCDC"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Edit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Close" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The result image

[image]

Comment: Can you provide more context? Of what type is the parent in your xml?

Comment: I have provide more context

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one :)

Edit:

the last line was not appearing :)

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/border_ui">
<com.google.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="a15284e3e927f18"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="false" />
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="#DCDCDC"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnEdit"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="Edit" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Delete" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        style="@style/myTextAppearance"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Close" />
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/adView"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_above="@id/linearLayout1">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1">
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/adView"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRuleNameTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Rule Name" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRuleName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:text="Rule Name" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutChecked"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutName"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvEnabledRule"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Enabled Rule" />
            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/chEnabledRule"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:enabled="false"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/LinearLayoutOption"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/LinearLayoutChecked">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvReceiveTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Receiver" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvReceiveNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOptionTitle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Forward Option" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvOnlyOrExceptNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="1\n2\n3\n4\n5\n6\n7\n8\n9\n10" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

ScrollView needs to be the root element in your xml. Add your elements to a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout that is the first and only child of your ScrollView.

Comment: Thanks! Is there other way to display more rows? I hope the toolbar buttons such as btnEdit, btnDeleet and btnClose always display on the bottom of screen.

Comment: You'll need to nest the views properly, but this can easily be done. What is the root element in your provided xml?

Comment: <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...   is root

Comment: My recommendation would be to change your RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout and then position the children using `layout_weight` and `weightSum`. As it stands, your ScrollView is trying to take up the full window because it is set to `match_parent` on `layout_height`, so  anything beneath it is never able to show.

Comment: Thanks!but if I change  RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout, the  toolbar buttons such as btnEdit, btnDeleet and btnClose can't always display on the bottom of screen.

Comment: They can if the root view matches parent in height and the `layout_weight`s are set properly.

Comment: Thanks! To jonstaff: your code still can't work well, I have edited my question, would you please to see?